# parameter targetplatformversion cannot be null - visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have windows 10 installed laptop with visual studio 2015 on it. I am trying to create a new project of universal Windows phone application. I always get the error Prameter targetplatformVersion cannot be null. 
Follwing are the screen shot of my machine

[image: VS 2015 Error]

I have tried installation and re-installing the [windows 10 sdk](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive) as well but no luck.

Loading an existing project where I can see targetPlatformVersion already is also not loading and throwing same error.

Any idea how I can track down this issue that Why do I get parameter targetplatformversion cannot be null?

**Update**

After doing detailed discussion with Karan from MS VS team we decided to run the repair and it worked.

Comment: If you want to create a windows phone 8.1 app, you need to install [windows 8.1 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk).

Comment: I am trying to develop windows 10 UAP

Comment: How can I fix this issue without complete re-installation of visual studio 2015. Sorry for typo

Comment: You mentioned in question: `I am trying to create a new project of universal Windows phone 8.1 application` and in comment: `I am trying to develop windows 10 UAP` - this is quite confusing. So what platform are you targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a Visual Studio repair should solve the problem.

---

Report this as a problem by clicking on the button on the top right [image]

Then follow the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt632287.aspx). Ensure you Provide a trace and heap dump - do not treat this as optional.

Reply back once you have done this and I will make sure this gets looked at.

Comment: I have reported the problem with trace and heap dump via recording tool. Can you please check?

Comment: Friend, Have you been able to look into it?

Comment: Haseeb, please mark this as answered if the repair worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the UWP SDKs manually -> no success

I reinstalled the UWP SDKs via VS Setup -> no success

I did a full repair of VS 2015 Community -> no success

Then I rolled back my Xamarin NuGet package for all my projects and removed the UWP project from my solution, deleted the local content, loaded the latest version from source control (VS Team Services) and then added the freshly loaded project to my solution. Now everything is back to normal. Looks like the Xamarin NuGet update somehow corrupted my UWP project.
So basically I just threw in the backup from Source Control. Hooray for Source Control!

**EDIT:** 
Before my workaround I reported the problem to the VS team. I just got an answer stating that there is a bug in NuGet that will get fixed in the future. Another workaround is also available. Here is the original answer:

> Thank you for your feedback! I'm sorry for the issue you're experiencing, as you described:
>
> "I upgraded Xamarin and the Xamarin NuGet package in my package. I did not change the project file of the UWP project. Since then I can't open my UWP project anymore. I tried reinstalling the UWP SDK outside of VS, then I reinstalled them through the VS installer and then I did a complete repair of VS. All without success. 
>   Any help is greatly appreciated since I can't continue on my project with this problem. 
>   Best regards :) "
>
> There was an issue with the Xamarin extension loading NuGet from a background thread. Xamarin updated their extension (grab the latest) to resolve this issue. We (The NuGet team) will release 3.5 next week, and that will make it work with the older versions of Xamarin or similarly misbehaving extensions.
>   The issue is tracked by this issue on github, you can also try the following private build to unblock you until 3.5 is officially released
>
> From Joel Verhagen on the thread linked above:
>   Hey guys, thanks for all the reports of this issue. I am working on getting a fix into dev right now. In the mean time, could you try this private build out for Visual Studio 2015 (dev14)?
>   https://dotnet.myget.org/F/nuget-vsix/vsix/NuGet.0d421874-a3b2-4f67-b53a-ecfce878063b-3.6.0.2363.vsix
>   You will need to uninstall the old version of NuGet first before trying this one.

TL;DR: If you got into this issue as a result of upgrading the Xamarin NuGet package, you can try my workaround or use the private NuGet build for VS 2015 or wait until NuGet 3.5 comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to download the Windows 10 standalone SDK from:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

And reinstall it.

And if its not working you can repair your Visual studio with the installer, this problem is a sign that something in your platform version setting is not correct.

And if thats also not working, you should have a look on your VS version if you have installed the update 2 from your community professional etc. version.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I already tried the same as I have provided the link in question is also for standalone sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Go To Uninstall application and select visual studio then click on Repair 
and the problem will be solved 
i had the same error while build a unity app 
and when i repaired visual every thing worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem when I have reinstall UWP SDK via Visual Studio Installer according [this solution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/answers/2271/view.html).

Citation:

I was able to fix it by following.

1. Go to Add/Remove programs and open Visual Studio installer in modify mode
2. Remove Windows Universal App feature
3. Reinstall Windows Universal App feature.
4. Now open Visual Studio>>New Project>>Blank App(Universal Windows)
   Thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/280/cant-create-a-new-blank-uwp-project.html