# Xamarin: Creating a blank project fails with the error targetplatformversion connot be null

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to create a blank Xamarin project in VS 2015 Community. It always fails with the error: the targetPlatformVersion cannot be null.

I've uninstalled 2015, repaired 2015, installed the Tools 1.4.1 SDK over and over again with varying results. The 'varying results' is strange to me. Sometimes it takes over 10 hours for the repair/reinstall to complete.

I really want to learn about this tech, so I reached out to the Xamarin team and this was their response:

"Hi Stephen,

We do not do code reviews. I would suggest contacting UWP support to get more insight on the problem.

Below is more information on how you can acquire support for this. You can also post your query on Stack overflow or MSDN forums.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support

Warm Regards,
....."

I stated:
"Sorry to be an idiot about this but what does ‘we do not code reviews’ mean?"

Their response:

"Basically we do not look at the code that is generated by customers. That was just a side note.
This seems to be like an issue with UWP. You can email UWP support to get to know the reason for this error. If they direct you to contact us, we can probe further."

I've tried to post my configuration, but stackoverflow doesn't like the format of my posted config info...apparently it needs to have four spaces and my didn't.

I can hopefully post that info upon request.

Comment: Searching google for "Xamarin targetPlatformVersion cannot be null" yielded may results, including your Xamarin Forums post with the same issue. One suggestion on SO was to repair the VS Install (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600908/parameter-targetplatformversion-cannot-be-null-visual-studio-2015) and some other ideas. And some more ideas on our forums: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64398/targetplatformversion-cannot-be-null

Comment: Nobody will like this answer, but after rebuilding my machine, I found that this was not a problem any further. It seems that something was wrong with an older C++ library in the registry and the fastest way to fix the problem was to nuke the machine and start over.